# Optional install with pip - ipython example

Tags: python, pip, ipython, packaging

The [Ipython documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html) mentions that there are different commands to install Ipython with pip, for example:

```
pip install "ipython[all]"

pip install "ipython[terminal]"

pip install "ipython[parallel]"

pip install "ipython[notebook]"
```

How does it work? How can I use such "options" for another package.

Comment: Those are `extras`. They can be specified in `setup.py`: https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `setup.py` in `ipython-3.0.0`.

```
extras_require = dict(
    parallel = [pyzmq],
    qtconsole = [pyzmq, 'pygments'],
    doc = ['Sphinx>=1.1', 'numpydoc'],
    test = ['nose>=0.10.1', 'requests'],
    terminal = [],
    nbformat = ['jsonschema>=2.0'],
    notebook = ['tornado>=4.0', pyzmq, 'jinja2', 'pygments', 'mistune>=0.5'],
    nbconvert = ['pygments', 'jinja2', 'mistune>=0.3.1']
)
```

For instance, if you enter `pip install "ipython[parallel]"`, `pip` will go to [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=ipython&submit=search) to find this package and download it.

So if you want to apply command like this to other packages, you have to make sure there is something like this in its `setup.py`.